# Perl - Can I get paths related to where a script resides and where it was executed from?

Tags: perl, path, directory, filenames, reserved-words

I'm looking for a way to get two pieces of information:

- The full path of where a script resides including its filename
- The full path of where a script was executed from

I know you can use `$0` to get the file name, but are there any other reserved variables that are native to Perl that will give me what I'm looking for?

I'd rather not use any special modules, but if it is the only way, then so be it.

Comment: "I'd rather not use any special modules" -- why? Note that there are a lot of modules that come packaged with the perl distribution, also.

Comment: @ether - for the same reason i don't like ketchup on hotdogs i suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `PWD` environment variable holds the current working directory, which should be the path the script was executed from.

You can derive the full path of the script with `$ENV{PWD}` and `$0`

**Edit**: providing sample code since it is hard for some to believe this is possible:

I may not have caught all the possible cases, but this should get very close:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "PWD: $ENV{PWD}\n";
print "\$0: $0\n";

my $bin = $0;
my $bin_path;

$bin =~ s#^\./##; # removing leading ./ (if any)

# executed from working directory
if ($bin !~ m#^/|\.\./#) {
  $bin_path = "$ENV{PWD}/$bin";
}
# executed with full path name
elsif ($bin =~ m#^/#) {
  $bin_path = $0;
}
# executed from relative path
else {
  my @bin_path = split m#/#, $bin;
  my @full_path = split m#/#, $ENV{PWD};

  for (@bin_path) {
    next if $_ eq ".";
   ($_ eq "..") ? pop @full_path : push @full_path, $_;
  }
  $bin_path = join("/", @full_path);
}

print "Script Path: $bin_path\n";
```

Output from test runs:

```
PWD: /tmp
$0: ../home/cmatheson/test.pl
Script Path: /home/cmatheson/test.pl

PWD: /home/cam
$0: ./test.pl
Script Path: /home/cam/test.pl

PWD: /usr/local
$0: /home/cam/test.pl
Script Path: /home/cam/test.pl

PWD: /home/cam/Desktop/foo
$0: ../../src/./git-1.7.3.2/../../test.pl
Script Path: /home/cam/test.pl
```

Comment: oh yeah.... i didn't even think of that.  thanks.  the only question i have about that is if when cron runs the script, will that still work?

Comment: `$PWD` contains the current working directory of the script, not the location of the script. For example, my cwd might be `~` but the script might be located in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @cam: This _does_ answer the second part of the question -- where the script is executed from. This cannot, however, be used to find the path to the location of the script. Remove the last sentence.

Comment: @Ether: precisely.  I did not recommend joining `$ENV{PWD}` and `$0` variables.  It is true, however, that `$0` will either be an absolute path (in which case he can use it directly), or it will be relative to `ENV{PWD}`, in which case the full path can be derived from the two.

Comment: @maxelost.  Please see my reply to @Ether.  It's possible I am mistaken, but I believe my answer is correct.

Comment: added some sample code to show how one might derive the script path from `PWD` and `$0`

Comment: thanks... no extra module solution = win  - i just have to see what happens when cron executes it, but hopefully it will still work as needed

Comment: Thanks @CheeseConQueso, I believe it will still work in that case, but if you have any problems just post another comment on here.

Comment: Your relative path code needs work, if I have a script in `../bin/script.pl` I can execute it as `../work/././test/../walls/./../../bin/script.pl`, assuming all needed directories exist.

Comment: Thanks @Ven'Tatsu, I have adjusted my code to work for this case.

Answer (score 7):

Using [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) and [`Cwd`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd        ();
use FindBin    ();
use File::Spec ();

my $full_path = File::Spec->catfile( $FindBin::Bin, $FindBin::Script );
my $executed_from_path = Cwd::getcwd();

print <<OUTPUT;
Full path to script: $full_path
Executed from path:  $executed_from_path
OUTPUT
```

Sample output (script saved as `/tmp/test.pl`):

```
alanhaggai@love:/usr/share$ /tmp/test.pl 
Full path to script: /tmp/test.pl
Executed from path:  /usr/share
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use File::Spec;

print File::Spec->rel2abs($0);
```

prints full path to your script including filename as you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is available with the built-in $FindBin::Bin variable (see [perldoc FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html)):

```
use FindBin;
use File::Spec;

print "the location of my script is: ", $FindBin::Bin, "\n";
print "the basename of my script is: ", $FindBin::Script, "\n";
print "the full path (symlinks resolved) of my script is: ", File::Spec->catfile($FindBin::RealBin, $FindBin::RealScript), "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked about special Perl stuff and no one has mentioned `__FILE__`. Check [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for it and more. I use this idiom often when I have a related subtree of files/scripts/modules–

```
use Path::Class qw( file );
use File::Spec;

my $self_file = file( File::Spec->rel2abs(__FILE__) );
print
    " Full path: $self_file", $/,
    "Parent dir: ", $self_file->parent, $/,
    " Just name: ", $self_file->basename, $/;
```

Answer (score 2):

For an solution that also handles symlinks,

```
use Cwd            qw( realpath );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

# Look for modules in the same dir as the script.
use lib dirname(realpath($0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the core [`Cwd`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) module to get the directory from which the script was executed, and the core [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) module to find the whole path to the script:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use File::Spec;

my $dir = getcwd();
print "Dir: $dir\n";

print "Script: " . File::Spec->rel2abs($0) . "\n";
```

Comment: `getcwd()` returns the current working directory of the script, not the location of the script. For example, my cwd might be `~` but the script might be located in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I took "The full path of where a script was executed from" to mean "the path where I was when I executed the script".

Comment: you are correct canspice, i do want to know the path where i was when i executed the script.  in addition, i want to know where the script itself lives